# Replace date "/" tobe "-" in existing column .csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in wind.csv format :

```
Date,Time,Wind
13/08/2020,12.00z, 13020knot
14/08/2020,12.00z, 14004knot
15/08/2020,12.00z, 10005knot
```

I want to replace the sign "/" to "-", the Date Data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("F:wind.csv") 
Date,Time,Wind
13/08/2020,12.00z, 13020knot
14/08/2020,12.00z, 14004knot
15/08/2020,12.00z, 10005knot

df.replace('/', '-', inplace=True)
```

it's not working,
How does the script python with the pandas?

I want to be like this :

```
13-08-2020,12.00z, 13020knot
14-08-2020,12.00z, 14004knot
15-08-2020,12.00z, 10005knot
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working what is the output it gives?

Comment: ``df.Date.str.replace("/", "-")`` ?

Comment: I will try, add .str

Comment: What do you mean it's not working what is the output it gives? Not change, it the same

Comment: BTW, I suggest using `pandas.to_datetime()` and changing your Date column from str to datetime format.

Comment: I have never used  `pandas.to_datetime ()`, because the dates I use are the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. It gets the result that you want but I don't know if it fit your desire.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Date.csv")
df["Date"] = df["Date"].str.replace("/","-")
```

This one work but take long line of code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Date.csv")
date = []
for d in df["Date"]:
    d = d.replace('/', '-')
    date.append(d)

df["Date"] = date
```

Comment: Thank You, Brother

Comment: @miko_design, i have made some modificaton, it's the good to use

Comment: if what is replaced is a value why can't it? attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-replace

Comment: I’ve you try to use the first solution. It will convert the dataframe content into a string before processing. Your error appears because sometime,  the content of "Date" column is a `int` type but not a `string`

To avoid this, before the for loop, in the second solution, convert all content of your dataframe into String by adding this code: `df = df.applymap(str)`